# How do I get the belongs_to association from a has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I've got a number of associated models and I'm not sure how to get an association that passes through all of them.

```
Trip.rb
  has_many :itineraries
  has_many :services, :through => :itineraries


Itinerary.rb
  belongs_to :Service

  def selected
    # can be true or false
  end


Service.rb
  has_many :itineraries
```

If I just wanted a full list of `Service`, I can just call @trip.services.  What I want, however, is just the list of Services from `Itineraries`s which are selected.  I can run @trip.itineraries.pluck(:service) but that returns just a regular old array.  Is it possible to get an AR association of `Services` objects scoped that way?

Comment: You have written `has_many :bees`.where is your `bees` model? And also its not `has_many :c`,a plural form should be used for `has_many`.Like `has_many :products`.

Comment: The models are actually Trip, Itinerary, and Service.  I have updated my demo code to reflect this.

Comment: What is the type of `a`, `b`, and `c`?

Comment: @tamer, I don't understand.  Is that question regarding the paragraph at the bottom?  Those `a`, `b` and `c` references are changed to reflect their models as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well if I understand you well, you can do it this way:

```
@trip.services.where(itinerary_id: your_selected_itineraries.ids)
```

Haven't tried this code because I'm not close to my rails machine, but I think it should work.

Comment: What is "your_selected_itineraries" in there?  Is that a method?  Living on a trip?